# Unity GetComponentInChild

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, get-childitem

I'm trying to create an inventory system. I have an Item class, and I want to change the visual appearance of the slot I create based on the data in this class, but it's not working. Where am I making a mistake?

This is my Inventory class, where I create a list and try to place the values from Item into the corresponding slots in the inventory. By the way, the inventory slots are prefabs.

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Item> InventoryList = new List<Item>();
    [Header("InventoryUI")]
    public GameObject InventorySlotPrefab;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        { 
            DisplayItemsOnSlots();
        }
      
    }

    public void AddItem(int _itemId,string _itemName, int _itemAmount, Sprite _sprite)
    { 
        Item newItem = Item.CreateInstance<Item>();
        newItem.SetItemDetails(_itemId,_itemName,_itemAmount, _sprite);
        InventoryList.Add(newItem);
    }
    

    public void DisplayItemsOnSlots()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < InventoryList.Count; i++)
        {
            Image itemImage = InventorySlotPrefab.GetComponentInChildren<Image>();
            itemImage.sprite = InventoryList[i].sprite;
        }
    
    }
}
```

This is my item class, which extends ScriptableObject.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Item", menuName ="ItemSystem/BasicItem")]
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int amount;
    public Sprite sprite;

    public void SetItemDetails(int _id, string _name, int _amount, Sprite _sprite)
    {
        this.id = _id;
        this.name = _name;
        this.amount = _amount;
        this.sprite = _sprite;
    }
}
```

Comment: well as the codes success is 100% dependant on the configuration of your UI.. its hard to tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < InventoryList.Count; i++)
{
    Image itemImage = InventorySlotPrefab.GetComponentInChildren<Image>();
    itemImage.sprite = InventoryList[i].sprite;
}
```

You are

- changing the `sprite` of the **prefab**,not of actual instances from the scene
- always assigning the `InventoryList[i].sprite` to the very same `Image` instance and thereby overwriting it -> if anything it would always end up with the last iteration's value

---

As I mentioned on one of your previous questions I would rather do something like e.g.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Item", menuName ="ItemSystem/BasicItem")]
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    public Sprite sprite;
    // as this is an asset it already has a built-in "name" anyway ;)
}
```

---

Then in your component you can interact with

```
public class PickableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    // reference the according asset
    public Item item;
    // and configure the amount via Inpsector
    [Min(1)] public int amount = 1;
}
```

then in your Inventory you store items and their amount. Either in a list

```
public class InventoryItem
{
    public Item item;
    public int amount;
}

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<InventoryItem> InventoryList = new ();
    
    // And then accordingly for adding new items
    private void AddItem(Item item, int amount)
    {
        // try find existing inventory item which is based on given item
        InventoryItem inventoryItem = null;
        foreach(var i in InventoryList)
        {
            if(i.item == item)
            {
                inventoryItem = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Or the same using System.Linq;
        //var inventoryItem = InventoryList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.item == item);

        // or if none was found create a new one
        if(inventoryItem == null)
        {
            inventoryItem = new InventoryItem();
            InventoryList.Add(inventoryItem);
        }

        // then simply apply the amount
        inventoryItem.amount += amount;

        RefreshItemsOnSlots();
    }

    ...
}
```

or you could actually also just go by a `Dictionary` and do

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dictionary<Item, int> InventoryList = new ();
    
    private void AddItem(Item item, int amount)
    {
        if(!InventoryList.ConainsKey(item))
        {
            InventoryList[item] = amount;
        }
        else
        {
            InventoryList[item] += amount;
        }

        RefreshItemsOnSlots();
    }

    ...
}
```

---

and then for displaying the UI accordingly I would probably go for object pooling (meaning when you remove items you only display the UI) and event driven display (meaning update the UI everytime something changed). First I'd use a dedicated component on the slots like e.g.

```
public class InventorySlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image image;
    public TMP_Text amountText;
}

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    ... // the stuff above ;)

    public RectTransform slotParent; // object to spawn slots under
    public InventorySlot InventorySlotPrefab;

    private readonly List<InventorySlot> slotInstances = new();

    private void RefreshItemsOnSlots()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Mathf.Max(InventoryList.Count, slotInstances.Count); i++)
        {
            if(i < InventoryList.Count) // for the items in inventory
            {
                InventorySlot currentSlot;

                if(i >= slotInstances.Count) // spawn required slot UI
                {
                    currentSlot = Instatiate(InventorySlotPrefab, slotParent);
                    slotInstances.Add(currentSlot);
                }
                else // or re-use existing slot UI if enough available
                {
                    currentSlot = slotInstances[i];
                }

                currentSlot.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                currentSlot.image.sprite = InventoryList[i].item.sprite;
                currentSlot.amountText = InventoryList[i].amount.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                // hide remaining slot UI instances
                // (could destroy as well - usually pooling is better in performance if done often)
                slotInstances[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or for the dictionary approach can't use indexer so use separate loops for initialize and de-initialize

```
    private void RefreshItemsOnSlots()
    {
        // for the items in inventory
        for (int i = 0; i < InventoryList.Count; i++)
        {
            if(i >= slotInstances.Count) // spawn required slot UI
            {
                currentSlot = Instatiate(InventorySlotPrefab, slotParent);
                slotInstances.Add(currentSlot);
            }
            else // or re-use existing slot UI if enough available
            {
                currentSlot = slotInstances[i];
            }

            currentSlot.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            currentSlot.image.sprite = InventoryList[i].item.sprite;
            currentSlot.amountText = InventoryList[i].amount.ToString();
        }

         // for remaining UI slots
        for(var i = InventoryList.Count; i < slotInstances.Count; i++)
        {
            currentSlot = slotInstances[i];
            currentSlot.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

---

and then a last bit would be to also use/remove items from the inventory

```
public bool RemoveItem(Item item, int amount)
{
    // try find existing inventory item which is based on given item
    InventoryItem inventoryItem = null;
    foreach(var i in InventoryList)
    {
        if(i.item == item)
        {
            inventoryItem = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Or the same using System.Linq;
    //var inventoryItem = InventoryList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.item == item);

    if(inventoryItem == null)
    {
        // don't have this item at all
        return false;
    }

    if(inventoryItem.amount < amount)
    {
        // do not have enough items
        return false;
    }

    inventoryItem.amount -= amount;

    if(inventoryItem.amount <= 0)
    {
        InventoryList.Remove(inventoryItem);
    }

    RefreshItemsOnSlots();
}
```

and again same for he dictionary approach

```
public bool RemoveItem(Item item, int amount)
{
    if(!InventoryList.ContainsKey(item))
    {
        // don't have that item at all
        return false;
    }

    if(InventoryList[item] < amount)
    {
        // do not have enough items
        return false;
    }

    InventoryList[item] -= amount;

    if(InventoryList[item] <= 0)
    {
        InventoryList.Remove(item);
    }

    RefreshItemsOnSlots();
}
```

---

and finally to show/hide your inventory UI you would simply toggle the `slotParent` accordingly:

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown.KeyCode.E)
    {
        slotParent.SetActive(!slotParent.activeSelf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you assign the prefab form project to the InventorySlotPrefab variable. If that's true, you are changing the sprite of the prefab, not the specific instance's sprite. You must attach Gameobject from the scene(probably item slot under Inventory) to the InventorySlotPrefab. Maybe you need a list of slots where slots[i] == InventoryList[i] or a more advanced structure where a slot contains an item.